# Windows 10 system repair disc made from mac + .vmdk files on USB made From Asus. Sufficient to recover Asus gaming pc?

Tags: data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery

I recently bought an Asus gaming laptop on a black Friday sale with the only downside it does not come with a built in CD drive. I made the system image backup on the USB successfully but when asking to make a windows 10 system repair disc, could not get it to work.

I had an existing USB CD drive with my 2014 Macbook pro computer and found out that it finds the drive but does not read discs at all when re-attached to the Asus gaming pc.

I partitioned, and found Windows 10.iso as that basic version of windows 10 was free at the time. Installed on my Mackbook pro and was able to make a windows 10 64 bit system repair disc from there.

Am wondering If when I'm able to get a USB cd drive in a couple weeks that works for Asus If I need to make a new windows 10 system repair disk from Asus or If what I have now is sufficient to recover the computer since the Asus is also 64 bit in order to not void the defective parts manufacturer warranty?

I have searched windows 10 recovery and found similar but not identical questions.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is designed to be recoverable from USB these days - as very few people still have an optical drive.

Get the [Media Creation Tool from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO) [on a PC, VM or Boot Camp, you can't do this directly on macOS], double click & follow the instructions.
Requires an 8GB USB stick or larger.

The resulting USB stick is usable as installer or repair.